# Is there any way to create a video element with just an image in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create a video feed with just an image in it. In other words the video will play for like 5 mins but all you'll see is an image.

I tried the `<video poster="">` attribute but I need the video to play and show the image.

This could be in html with javascript or jquery.

Comment: Is this so you can still have the audio from the video playing without the visuals?

Comment: The problem is that I am implementing a video conference and if the user does not have a webcam I need to be able to still have sound but I will place the image for the video.

Comment: Can't you just place an image on top of the video element via css?

Comment: It will work if I can place the image inside the video element because there is a function that waits until the video feed is loaded and if the user does not have a webcam it breaks.

Comment: does this post help at all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718109/how-can-i-display-an-image-if-browser-does-not-support-html5s-video-tag displaying the image in the video tag.