# Fallback image when mobile browser don't support WebM video

Tags: javascript, html, webm

I have a WebM video using the mobile browser. When these browsers don't support WebM, I want to show an image:

```
<video
  src={video}
  autoPlay>
  <img src={poster} />
</video>
```

But in mobile safari/chrome/firefox browser in iOS, It shows a black background with an can't play icon. It doesn't fallback to show an image as I expect.

And I also try to add `poster` attribute to `video` tag:

```
<video
  poster={poster}
  src={video}
  autoPlay>
  <img src={poster} />
</video>
```

And this:

```
<video
  loop
  autoPlay>
  <source src={video} type="video/webm" />
  <img src={poster} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} />
</video>
```

It doesn't work, either.

Anyone have a clue on how to show an image When the browser doesn't support WebM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display an image if browser does not support HTML5's <video> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718109/how-can-i-display-an-image-if-browser-does-not-support-html5s-video-tag)

Comment: @bhansa here it's not the tag that is not supported but the media. To OP, you could always listen to the `error` event. I guess (not tested) that the poster + `onerror = e => this.src = ""` would do it.

Comment: Oh actually Safari doesn't place the poster again when the src is reset... You'll then probably have to replace your video element with an img directly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) said, It's not the tag that supported but the media, and most mobile browsers don't place the poster again when then src is reset.

So I have to replace the image directly.

I use React as my stack, here is my solution:

```
class App extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    isSupportWebM: true,
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const videoElement = document.querySelector('.video');
    videoElement.addEventListener('error', () => {
      this.setState({
        isSupportWebM: false,
      });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    // remove the listener
  }

  render(){
     const {
       isSupportWebM,
     } = this.state;
     return (
       <div>
         {
           isSupportWebM
           ? <video src={...}></video>
           : <img src={...} />
         }
       </div>
     )
  }
}
```